# Internet Explorer 10 Ignores CSS 'overflow:auto' Style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I've got this weird problem w/ IE10.  I have a table and I've got a UI widget (jqTree) in one of the cells.
Now, this tree view can fill up with a lot of data so I wanted to fix the size it'd take up on screen.  I also need to let the user scroll to any part of the tree view.  This works great on Chrome, but not at all on IE 10.

```
    <td style="vertical-align:top">
        <div class="HiddenInput" style="visibility:hidden">
            <div style="overflow:auto; width:350px; height:750px; border-style:solid">
                <div id="TreeView"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
```

The outer most div is just to hide the tree view until I receive data.  In IE10, when I populate the tree view, if it totally ignores the bounds set by the div immediately above it as if it wasn't there, even though the div's border is clearly visible.

I read somewhere that IE requires a DOCTYPE tag, but that didn't fix this.

Comment: What render-mode do the IE Developer Tools report? IE7 Quirks-mode or Standards mode?

Comment: A doctype is REQUIRED for all modern web pages and should be the first thing you put on any page.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out.  IE10 was defaulting to rendering my page in IE7 standards mode.  Moving to IE8/9/10 fixes the issue.

So if you want to ensure that your page is rendered in the most recent version of IE (or a specific version) try using:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
```

More details about this meta tag here:

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/01/19/internet-explorer-8-document-and-browser-modes/

Comment: For IE10, using a proper doctype renders this meta tag unnecessary.  It is only necessary if you're aiming for IE8/IE9 compatibility and have other wonkiness in your page/local settings which triggers IE7 compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<td style="vertical-align:top">
    <div class="HiddenInput" style="display:none">
        <div style="overflow:auto; width:350px; height:750px; border-style:solid">
            <div id="TreeView"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

and after the treeview filled up, change the display property:

```
  <div class="HiddenInput" style="display:block;">
```

Comment: Didn't change anything, same behavior as before.  Thanks though